# React Native Database and ORM compatibility

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo, prisma

I am planning to build a React Native app using expo and wanted to know how compatible would using Prisma be. I only have worked with mongoDb and I have not seen many people use it and wanted to switch to another db using Prisma but I saw it had compatibility issues in 2021 and not much results from then on.

I am fairly new to development and wanted to know what would be the best options/ libraries  to-

- Have both one time payment and monthly payment.
- Have a real time chat system.
- Login Auth.
- Book an appointment using a calendrer system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use prisma as ORM for your backend, but you cannot run prisma on the client unfortunately. [There is a feature request for it](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5011)

This might be critical if you are going to build an app that fully or partially works offline. If it't the case I can recommend going for [Type ORM](https://typeorm.io/) It is fully written in TS and can work with react native and SQLite.

Comment: My app does not need to work while its offline. 
Could you elaborate how Prisma client and backend works ? I fail to understand how Prisma works even when reading the docs . Basically my app does not see any reason to have any offline features.